# At about age 30

Tags: prepositions, numbers, ellipsis

Is is grammatically right to leave out the definite article in the following sentence?

what would change if the word about were not added?

- *[At about (the) age 30, Jesus was baptized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_(number))*

Comment: "to *leave* out".. **left** is not the infinitive but the past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what words behave like _age_ regarding possible omissible material form the full prepositional phrase?

Comment: I think it's really more about the word ***thirty*** (whether rendered in digits or letters) rather than ***age***. Note that *He was baptized at ten* could mean ***age ten*** or ***ten o'clock***, depending on context. You might also consider the choice between *He was baptized in Liverpool* and *...in **the city of** Liverpool* (and note that those *particular* two are equivalent, but there could actually be a significant difference if we substitute ***London*** for ***Liverpoool*** there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers what effect on grammaticality would adding the word *old* have on all possible combinations? At the age of 30 (years), At age 30 (years), 
At 30 (years)“

Comment: You'd always need to precede ***old*** by ***years***. There's nothing *syntactically* wrong with ***at the age of 30 years old***, but no-one would normally include both ***age*** and ***years old*** in the same construction. Most people wouldn't usually bother including *either*, since the intended meaning of the important bit *(**30**)* would normally be obvious anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker of American English, I'd say

> ... at about age thirty

or

> ... at about the age of thirty

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker of British English, I would use either "around aged 30", or "around the age of 30" instead of "at about age 30".

The related things to know here are:

- 'at about' is synonymous with 'around'
- If 'age' is acting as a linking verb and '30' is the complement, then 'age' should be inflected to 'aged', because your sentence is in past simple tense. Furthermore, if 'age' is a linking verb, there is no reason to put the article 'the' in front of it.
- If 'age' is acting as a noun, then 'of' must be placed between 'age' and '30', to represent the relationship between the words 'age' and '30' that gives the intended meaning. 'age' can also be used as a length of time, so 'age 30' could mean something entirely different to your intention. Furthermore, if 'age of 30' is our noun phrase, then we need to place 'the' before it, because it's a definite thing.

I would never say "at about the age 30" or "at about age 30", as it seems grammatically confused. Instead, I might say "At about aged 30", or "at about the age of 30", because they are grammatically correct. I would normally replace 'at about' with 'around' though.

EDIT. Without 'about', the correct phrases would be "at aged 30", or "at the age of 30".

EDIT EDIT. I would use "around aged 30", even if we were talking in present simple tense.

Comment: Rather than “around aged 30” I'd make it “aged around 30”.

Comment: _at aged 30_ or _at age 30_?

Comment: I would use 'at about the age of 30'.

Comment: You wouldn't say **around age thirty**  (rather than "aged")?

Comment: *He looks to be around **age** thirty* and *He was around **aged** thirty* ?

Comment: I'm questioning you specifically about your your statement at the top of your answer: *I would use either "around **aged** 30" ...* [my emphasis]   Just want to make sure you would really say that and it wasn't a typo.

Comment: The top of my answer wasn't a typo.

Comment: @BradGraham That too caught my eye, as it wouldn't fly in American English. Someone can be *aged around 30*, *around age 30*, *around 30*, *around the age of 30*, *at about the age of 30*, or *at the age of about 30*, but never *around aged 30*.

Comment: *Around aged 30* is completely unidiomatic.